# MySql: Get Records with last different values

Tags: mysql

Here is my table data

```
id | name | Status
-----------------
1    ABC    Sys START
2    ABC    START  
3    ABC    STOP
4    ABC    Sys START
5    ABC    START
6    ABC    STOP
7    ABC    Sys STOP
8    ABC    Sys START
9    XYZ    START
10    XYZ    STOP
11    ABC    Sys STOP
12    ABC    Sys START
13   ABC    START
14    ABC    STOP
15    ABC    Sys STOP
16    ABC    Sys START
17    ABC    START
18    ABC    STOP
19    ABC    Sys STOP
20    ABC    Sys START
21    ABC    START
22    ABC    STOP
23    ABC    Sys STOP
24    ABC    Sys START
```

Desired Output

```
13    ABC    START
14    ABC    STOP
17    ABC    START
18    ABC    STOP
21    ABC    START
22    ABC    STOP
```

I just want to get all values with START and STOP with last changed name.

Like I have value XYZ with id=9 and status="START" and value changed after it with value ABC id=11 and status="START".

So value required from last changed name with status "START" and "STOP".

Is it possible with single query? Or i need to use multiple queries?

Comment: It seems that a single query would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a simpler solution, but here's one idea...

```
SELECT x.* 
  FROM my_table x
  JOIN
     ( SELECT name
            , MAX(id) prev 
         FROM my_table 
        WHERE status IN ('START','STOP') 
        GROUP 
           BY name
     ) y
    ON y.name <> x.name
   AND y.prev < x.id 
 WHERE x.status IN ('START','STOP');
```